# Excel PivotTable DataRange puzzle

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am running into a puzzle with Excel PivotTables and the DataRange behavior. It does not seem to work as expected when there are no Column fields. I want to select all the data cells associated with one particular PivotField from the Row items, how do I do that?

Say I have the following data table:

```
a   b   x   y   z
A   A   1   9   0
A   B   2   10  0
A   C   3   11  0
A   D   4   12  0
B   A   5   13  0
B   B   6   14  0
B   C   7   15  0
B   D   8   16  0
```

and I create a simple PivotTable in tabular form that has two Row items (a,b) and only one Value item (Sum of x). Then the DataRange for the PivotField a.A

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("a").PivotItems("A").DataRange.Select
```

selects the following cells (marked with an Asterix):

```
a   b   Sum of x
A   A   *1
    B   *2
    C   *3
    D   *4
B   A   5
    B   6
    C   7
    D   8
```

Great! But here comes the oddity. When adding another Value item (y) to the PivotTable the same code selects the following cells:

```
a   b   Sum of x    Sum of y
A   A   1           9
    B   *2          10
    C   *3          11
    D   *4          12
B   A   *5          13
    B   6           14
    C   7           15
    D   8           16
```

How does that make any sense? However if I add a dummy Column item (z) then the result is what I would have expected in from the previous scenario:

```
        z   Values
        0
a   b   Sum of x    Sum of y
A   A   *1          *9
    B   *2          *10
    C   *3          *11
    D   *4          *12
B   A   5           13
    B   6           14
    C   7           15
    D   8           16
```

But I really don't want to add a dummy to make this work. Any other way to make this selection work for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I'd never noticed that.

One of the first things I do when creating a pivot table in Excel 2007 or later is select "Classic Pivot Table layout" in the pivot table options menu:

[image]

I've been doing it long enough that I kind of forget the problems it solves. But I now know that it solves this one!